# Oracle giving different times after changing timezone and converting to char

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have trying to convert the UTC time to local time in Oracle Developer as per query below. I needed it in a particular format after conversion but after conversion to character the time comes out to be completely different. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here please.

```
select e.encntr_id
,to_char(e.reg_dt_tm,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mm') as reg_dt_tm
,to_char(from_tz (cast(e.reg_dt_tm as timestamp),'UTC')  at time zone 
            'Australia/Sydney','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mm') as aest_reg_char
,from_tz (cast(e.reg_dt_tm as timestamp),'UTC')  at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' as aest_reg

from encounter e
where e.ENCNTR_ID in(123) 

encntr_id   reg_dt_tm           aest_reg_char       aest_reg
123         2022-03-03 05:03    2022-03-03 16:03    03/MAR/22 04:51:12.000000000 PM AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
TO_CHAR(
  from_tz (cast(e.reg_dt_tm as timestamp),'UTC')  at time zone 'Australia/Sydney',
  'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mm:ss.ff TZR'
)
```

Or change the default `TIMESTAMP_TZ` format in SQL Developer:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR';
```

and then run the query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=026a7cef10aba92564ab70da105baaa3)*